# Pytorch module 'torch' has no attribute 'logsoftmax'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, torch, pytorch-geometric

I am testing two trained model but getting an error unexpectedly. I search on the google but did not find any satisfactory result.

**Code**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    normalize = transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                     std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    tfs = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        normalize,
    ])

    model1 = timm.models.swin_base_patch4_window7_224(pretrained=False, num_classes=15)
    model1 = torch.nn.DataParallel(model1)
    model1.load_state_dict(torch.load('/media/cvpr/CM_22/OOD_CV/swin15_best.pth.tar')['state_dict'],strict=False)
    model1 = model1.cuda()
    model1.eval()

    model2 = timm.models.convnext_base(pretrained=False, num_classes=15)
    model2 = torch.nn.DataParallel(model2)
    model2.load_state_dict(torch.load('convnext15_best.pth.tar')['state_dict'],strict=False)
    model2 = model2.cuda()
    model2.eval()

    dataset = PoseData(tfs)
    loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=False, drop_last=False, num_workers=4)

    image_dir = []
    preds = []
    for image, pth in loader:
        image_dir.append(list(pth))
        image = image.cuda()

        with torch.no_grad():

            model1.eval()
            pred1 = model1(image)
            model2.eval()
            pred2 = model2(image)

            entropy1 = -torch.sum(torch.softmax(pred1[:, :10], dim=1) * torch.logsoftmax(pred1[:, :10], dim=1), dim=-1,
                                  keep_dim=True)
            entropy2 = -torch.sum(torch.softmax(pred2[:, :10], dim=1) * torch.logsoftmax(pred2[:, :10], dim=1), dim=-1,
                                  keep_dim=True)
            entropy = entropy1 + entropy2

            pred = torch.softmax(pred1[:, :10], dim=1) * (entropy - entropy1) / entropy + torch.softmax(pred2[:, :10],
                                                                                                        dim=1) * (
                               entropy - entropy2) / entropy
            pred = torch.argmax(pred[:, :10], dim=1)
            p = []
            for i in range(pred.size(0)):
                p.append(name_list[pred[i].item()])
        p = np.array(p)
        preds.append(p)
        print(len(np.concatenate(preds)))

    image_dir = np.array(sum(image_dir, []))
    preds = np.concatenate(preds)

    csv = {'imgs': np.array(image_dir), 'pred': np.array(preds),
           }
    csv = pd.DataFrame(csv)
    print(csv)

    csv.to_csv('results.csv', index=False)
```

**Traceback**

```
  return _VF.meshgrid(tensors, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/cvpr/CM_22/OOD_CV/test.py", line 92, in <module>
    entropy1 = -torch.sum(torch.softmax(pred1[:, :10], dim=1) * torch.logsoftmax(pred1[:, :10], dim=1), dim=-1,
AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'logsoftmax'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [`nn.functional.logsoftmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.log_softmax.html?highlight=torch%20logsoftmax) which is the functional form of [`nn.LogSoftmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LogSoftmax.html#torch.nn.LogSoftmax).

Comment: I have made changes in entropy1 and entropy but now getting new error "TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'dim'"

Comment: Could you show the new updated code?

Comment: entropy1 = -torch.sum(torch.softmax(pred1[:, :10], dim=1) * nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)(pred1[:, :10]), dim=-1,keepdim=True)

Comment: This is a problem with the dimensions. Can you tell what the shape of `pred1` is?